# setAttributeでvideoタグにcontrolsを追加したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

setAttributeでvideoタグにcontrolsを追加したいのですが、
controlsに第二引数のvalueはないので、element.setAttribute(name,value)に反してしまいエラーとなってしまいます。

どのようにしてvideoタグにcontrolsを追加したらよいか分かりません。
分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

変数videoがvideo要素を指している変数だとして、

```
video.setAttribute('controls', '');
```

です。実際は2番目のパラメータに何を入れても同じ意味です。setAttribute()を使わずに、

```
video.controls = true;
```

でもよいです。